# trouble sharing object between two component using BehaviorSubject Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to share an object between two components through a service.

The component `option-post.component` is meant to display this object or an array of those objects. The  component `option-post-choix.component` is used to select which objects you want `option-post.component` to display. I use `option-data.service` to share the data between both components.

I can see with the `console.log('service recv', data)` in `option-data.service` that my data arrives to the service but in `option-post.component` I can see with `console.log('recv',this.option_select)` that I only receive an empty array. I also use `rxjs/BehaviorSubject` because `option-post` subscribe only after the data being emit by the service.

The logic is really inspired by [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865348/subscriber-doesnt-receive-value-from-next) and  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706497/how-to-create-behavior-subject-for-object-and-subscribe-to-it-on-another-compone)  but I'm a bit clueless right now.
I've already check that my service is only provide one time in `module.ts`

My question is: why the array is empty in `option-post.component` after it pass through my service, where he is not ?

**option-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Options } from './option-post-choix/option';

@Injectable()
export class OptionDataService {
  private getDataSubject: BehaviorSubject<Options[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  getData$: Observable<Options[]> = this.getDataSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {
  }

  getData(data) {
  console.log('service recv', data);
  this.getDataSubject.next(data);
 }
}
```

**option-post-choix.component.ts**

```
import { Options } from './option';
import { OptionDataService } from '../option-data.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-option-post-choix',
templateUrl: './option-post-choix.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./option-post-choix.component.css']
})
export class OptionPostChoixComponent implements OnInit {

 // simulation data
 options_choix = [
  new Options(0, 'Option 1', 'texte option 1', 15),
  new Options(1, 'Option 2', 'texte option 2', 150),
  new Options(2, 'Option 3', 'texte option 3', 50)
 ];

 constructor(private location: Location) { }

 option_select: Array<Options> = [];
 private dataTrans: OptionDataService = new OptionDataService;

 onValidClicked() {
 this.dataTrans.getData(this.option_select);
 this.location.back();
 }

 addOpt(opt, check) {
  console.log('id ', opt.id, 'is', check);
  if (!check) {
   this.option_select.push(opt);
  } else {
   this.option_select.splice(this.option_select.findIndex(x => x.id === opt.id), 1);
  }
}
```

**option-post.component.ts**

```
import { OptionDataService } from '../option-data.service';
import { Options } from '../option-post-choix/option';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
selector: 'app-option-post',
templateUrl: './option-post.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./option-post.component.css']
})
export class OptionPostComponent implements OnInit {

 public option_select: Options[];

 constructor(private router: Router, private data: OptionDataService) {

 }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.data.getData$.subscribe(option_select =>
  this.option_select = option_select);
  console.log('recv', this.option_select); //empty array []

 }

 addOption() {
  this.router.navigate(['/home/optionPostChoix']);
 } 

}
```

**option-post.component.html**

```
<div class="element_liste">
      <div class="option_box"  *ngFor="let opt of options_select">
          {{opt.titre}}
          <div class="option_elem">
            {{opt.texte}}
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**option.ts**
Is where I declare my object `Options` that I want to share

```
export class Options {
constructor(
    public id: number,
    public titre: string,
    public texte: string,
    public prix: number
 ) {}
}
```

Comment: inject service instead of creating new service in option-post-choix.component.ts.  Same instance of service should be present in both component. then it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to [Nabin Kumar Khatiwada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7636024/nabin-kumar-khatiwada) my problem is solve :

change in `option-post-choix.component`
from

`constructor(private location: Location){}`

to

`constructor(private location: Location, private dataTrans: OptionDataService) {}`

and remove

`private dataTrans: OptionDataService = new OptionDataService;`